# wireless network won't connect automatically

Tags: wireless

wireless network worked fine first time i set it up but when i rebooted it wouldnt start automatically. note that i used "sudo pppoeconf" to connect to my service provider

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Right click on the network icon -> edit connection -> click wireless tab -> click on your wireless name -> click on edit on the right side, make sure to check connect automatically checkbox

[image]