# How do I get my wireless to automatically start after reboot

Tags: 11.10, wireless

I am running Ubuntu 11.10, and finally have figured out how to get my Broadcom BCM4306 wireless working.  Unfortunately, I still have to enter the following commands "sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb"  and  "sudo modprobe b43" then enable networking and enable wireless every time after I reboot.  Does anyone know how to make this process happen automatically?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm surprised that you need to do this - have you tried instructions such as this to ensure your wireless is automatically recognised?  http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2011/09/fixing-broadcom-43xx-wireless-card.html

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about that wireless device in special, but I do know something about modules

Concerning the modules, the commands you posted seem a bit confusing, as they first remove the module "b43" and then load it again:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb
#this removes (-r) the modules "b43" and "ssb" if they are already loaded (see *man modprobe*)

sudo modprobe b43
#this loads the module "b43"
```

To load a module at boot time, add the module-name to the end of the file **/etc/modules** (you can edit the file executing `sudo gedit /etc/modules`, for more info see *man modules* and *man modprobe*)

To explicitly prevent loading a module at boot time, you can *blacklist* it, by adding the module-name to the end of the file **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**

So maybe in your case, it could be enough to add "ssb" into /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

Try it out and share with us :)

Answer (score 2):

Under 12.04 you just need to comment out `blacklist bcm43xx` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

To do that, run this command in the Terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

This will open the file in a graphical text editor. In the editor, find the `blacklist bcm43xx` line and put a `#` character at the beginning of it. Save the file and quit the text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of putting `sudo modprobe b43` in the */etc/modules* just put `b43`.

I also commented out the *b43* line in */etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf*.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get your modules straightened out (+1 to @zipzap for mentioning **/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf**), make sure that the interface is marked connect automatically.

If You're using Network Manager, **Edit Connetcions**->**"Wireless Tab**->**Select Connection**->**Edit** and make sure "Connect automatically" is checked. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30574/wireless-network-wont-connect-automatically) for an image.

If you're not using Network Manager, add the name of your interface to the "`auto lo`" line, using `sudoedit /etc/network/interfaces`. **Note:** Be careful to not disrupt the "`auto lo`" line, or you will be **very unhappy**.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I wasn't able to edit the `blacklist.conf` file using `gksu` as it wasn't opening the file in any editor.

If I just open `blacklist.conf` by double clicking it used to open in read only mode.

So, the way I got it working is, from terminal I ran this query

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

and added `#` before `blacklist bcm43`.

Comment: Please note that when running graphical programs like `gedit` as `root`, `gksu`/`gksudo` (or `kdesudo` in Kubuntu) [should be used, instead of straight `sudo`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo).